# installing plyr on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, r

I'm trying to install plyr on ubuntu 14.04 and getting the this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘plyr’ ...
** package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include      -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O3 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2    -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘plyr’
* removing ‘/home/ignacio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/plyr’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp1Rmysx/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("plyr", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you need https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/r-cran-plyr

Choose the version you need from the Published versions section, then on the right you will see Downloadable files.

They are debs so no compiling required.